# Add, remove input box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So what i am trying to do is to have

1.add function to add an input box

2.remove function to remove the last input box in the list

3.sort function to sort the list of input texts by alphabetic order

I think my add function is working, but i am running into problem when i am trying to remove the last input box or trying to sort it.
Any idea or suggestion would be very much appreciated. thanks

```html
<form id="mainform" >
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
<button onclick="remove()">remove</button>
<button onclick="sort()">sort</button>
</form>

<script>
    var i = 0;
    var count =0;
    function add() {  
         var x= document.createElement("INPUT");
         x.setAttribute("type", "text");
         x.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");
         i += 1;
         count=count+1;
         document.body.appendChild(x);
    }    
    function remove(){
         i -= 1;
         count=count-1;
    }
    
    function sort(){
         var x;
         x=count;
         var strings=[]
         var t;
         var i=0;
         t=x;
         while(t!=0){
              strings.push(document.forms["mainform"].elements[i].value);
              t=t-1;
              i=i+1}
   
         strings=strings.sort()
         var j=0;
         var msg='';
         while(x!=0){
              var msg=msg+strings[j]+'\n';
              document.forms["mainform"].elements[j].value=strings[j];
              j=j+1;
              x=x-1;}
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show any error messages or state why it isn't working.

Comment: Your remove function not doing anything to the elements, you can hide them by setting display to none if you don't want show it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your add function adds the inputs directly to the body, while your sort function is looking for elements in the form['mainform'] element.

Your remove function is just decrementing your iterator without actually affecting the form at all.

Answer (score 0):

That would do the job:

```html
    <form id="mainform" >
    <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()"></input>
    <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="remove()"></input>
    <input type="button" value="sort" onclick="sort()"></input>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        function add() {  
             var x= document.createElement("INPUT");
             x.setAttribute("type", "text");
             x.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");
             x.setAttribute("class", "someInput");
             document.body.appendChild(x);
        }
        
        function remove() {
          var childs = document.body.getElementsByClassName("someInput");
          if(childs.length > 0) {
            document.body.removeChild(childs[childs.length - 1]);
          }
        }
        
        function sort(){
          var hash = {};
          var childs = document.body.getElementsByClassName("someInput");
          
          // Map each element to its value
          for(var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            var currentElement = childs[i];
            hash[currentElement.value] = currentElement;
          }
          
          // Remove all added elements
          for(var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            var currentElement = childs[i];
            document.body.removeChild(currentElement);
          }
          
          // Sort by map keys, and add all elements back sorted
          Object.keys(hash).sort().forEach(function(v, i) {
            document.body.appendChild(hash[v]);
          });
       }
    </script>
```

Please note that I replaced the `button` elements with `input` elements in order to prevent the form from being submitted.

Also pay attention that I marked each inserted textbox with class named "someInput". That will make our life easier when we want to query and get all the inserted textboxes.